# Log4Net on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows, events, log4net, viewer

I've been working on a web application using Visual Studio 2010 on a Windows 7 OS.

I used Log4Net for logging on the Event Viewer and that worked out great, meaning that everything is being correctly logged on my Windows 7 Event Viewer.

After installing this same project on a Windows Server 2003 Machine, I've noticed that nothing get's logged...

I already added the ASPNET on the Administrators group of the Windows Server 2003 machine but still the problem persists...

On the AssemblyInfo.cs file I added:

[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator()]

On Web.config file I added:

...

    

...

    
      
      
       -->

```
<appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender" >
  <param name="LogName" value="MyLog" />
  <param name="ApplicationName" value="MyApplication" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<!-- Setup the root category, add the appenders and set the default level -->
<root>
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
</root>
<!-- ApplicationKit category - the presentation UI -->
<logger name="MyLogger">
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
</logger>
```

And finally on the code behind:

...
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
Ilog log = LogManager.GetLogger("MyLogger");
...

I already created the MyLog key value on:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog

But still, nothing gets logged there.

I'm 100% percent sure this works perfectly on Windows 7.

Do I need to make some oyher special configuration on Windows Server 2003?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. Are you using INFO level or above to check your code? 2. Is the FileAppender working ok? 3. Can you create a console application with log4net+eventlogappender and test it on the win-2003 server (this is to isolate the permissions issue)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...

As it turned out I also had to give the NETWORK SERVICE full permissions to the following key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog

Voila